# Double Toolbar is Showing

Tags: java, xml, android-fragments, double, toolbar

How to remove two toolbars from a fragment?

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

even after using this command the second blank toolbar remains and the top toolbar disappears.

Comment: change the theme of activity from manifest, use Noactionbar theme, it will remove yout default toolbar from activity

Answer (score 0):

Use NoActioonBar Theme instead of Default one in Manifest file

```
 <activity .....
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

add no action bar line in manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

then add in your styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```